# There are 56 teams in a knockout tournament, then how many matches has to be played to select the champion?

Tags: combinatorics

''There are 56 teams in a knockout tournament, then how many matches has to be played to select the champion?''

I found this in a question paper, and I am stuck to solve this problem.

I have proceeded to solve it like this:

Round 1: $\frac{56}{2}=28$ matches

Round 2:  $\frac{28}{2}=14$ matches

Round 3: $\frac{14}{2}=7$ matches

Now I can't find how many matches will be played in Round 4.

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Each match knocks out one player. How many players have to be knocked out in order to determine the winner?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I realized the logic but wouldn't it be unfair giving a team a pass without winning through round 4.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott Thanks I got it.

Comment: @Ayan: You’re welcome.

Comment: @Dhruv: There’s nothing in the statement of the problem that requires a division into rounds at all. Perhaps the players are numbered $1$ through $56$, the first match is between $1$ and $2$, the next match is between the winner of that and $3$, and so on, the winner of each match then playing the lowest-numbered player who has not yet been eliminated. If the tournament *is* arranged in tree form, some players are guaranteed to have a bye, since $56$ is not a power of $2$.

Comment: @Dhruv yeah I also thought that, it will be unfair

Comment: I think is 6 matches because $2^6=64$ and I suggest should be more than 5 matches because $2^5=32$ and there are 56 matches.

Comment: @Kenny: You seem to be using "match" to mean the same thing as the OP's "round." You're right that there must be at least 6 rounds, but there may be as many as 55. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The interesting thing about this question is that it doesn't matter how the tournament is structured. For example:

- We could randomly assign a bye in the first round to 8 of the teams. At the end of the second round, there would be 24 teams left who had played, and the 8 who'd had a bye, leaving 32 teams. In each subsequent round, all remaining teams will participate, until one remains.
- We could have every team play each round until the fourth round, at which point only 7 teams remain. One of these teams is randomly assigned a bye in the fourth round, and the rest play, so that in the fifth round, 4 teams remain, and every team plays each subsequent round until one remains.
- We could number the teams from 1 to 56. The first round is a match between teams 1 and 2. The second round pits team 3 against the winner of the first round, the third round pits team 4 against the winner of the second round, and so on (more generally, for any integer $1\le n\le54,$ in round $n+1,$ team $n+2$ plays against the winner of round $n$).

Of course, these arrangements aren't equally "fair," whatever that means, but regardless, it turns out that the same number of games will be played! This is because each game will result in one loser, who is then removed from the set of possible winners, until only one team remains. Hence, 55 games must be played (which you can verify to be the case in the three disparate examples I gave above).